# error when converting to list

Tags: c#, json, wcf

WCF

```
public List<string> getClientes()
{
        using (var context = new Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer())
        {
            return context.Cliente.Select(x => x.CLNombre).ToList();
        }
}
```

.cs

```
[OperationContract]
List<string> getClientes();
```

Web App ASPX.cs

```
if (Request.QueryString["getClientes"] != null)
{
    CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService wsclient = new CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService();

    List<CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService> clientList = wsclient.getClientes().ToList();
}
```

I'm getting a error on this line of code

```
wsclient.getClientes().toList();
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.list <string> to system.collections.generic.list < CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService>

What should I do to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is returning `List<string>` while you are assigning it's reference to some other type of list i.e. `List<CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService>`, change your line:

```
List<CivarTransporteService.View.CatalogsService> clientList =wsclient.getClientes().ToList();
```

to:

```
List<string> clientList =wsclient.getClientes().ToList();
```

and you also don't need `ToList()` at the end of it just `wsclient.getClientes()` is fine, as you are already returning `List<T>` from service.

so it will be:

```
List<string> clientList =wsclient.getClientes();
```